# Play GNU screen terminal sessions and slow them down

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, recording, session

I have some log files made with GNU screen which I would like to watch.
These use elinks and vim, it is not simple bash text.

If I use cat, it almost works save that it is too fast. Is there a way to slow it down? I thought about writing a simple C program just like cat but sleeping a fraction of a second between outputting each character, unless there is a simpler way.

Since it looks like GNU screen is not the right tool to share, record and play the Linux terminal, I am opened to suggestions about using better tools next time, so I won't have this problem again.

Comment: I think I better use script and scriptreplay for recording and not GNU screen logging.

Comment: For what it's worth, an earlier [`slowcat`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/misc_tools-snapshots/blob/master/src/slowcat/slowcat.c), which I use with `script`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following C program to cat(1) a file pausing a certain number of microseconds after each character. Usage example:

$ ./slowcat screenlog.0 2000

if I want to stop while watching, I just send the SIGSTOP signal from my keyboard (Ctrl-S). I then send SIGCONT (Ctrl-Q) to resume. Ctrl-C to quit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int c, ms_wait;
  FILE *fp;
  char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */

  if (argc == 3) {
    ms_wait = atoi(argv[2]);
  } else if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file [ms_wait]\n", prog);
    exit(1);
  } else {
    ms_wait = 1000;
  }

  if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv);
    exit(1);
  }

  while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    usleep(ms_wait);
  }

  return 0;
}
```